# grails 2.4.2 simple captcha plugin installation error

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, simplecaptcha

I am using grails 2.4.2 and trying to install simple captcha plugin but when i run the app, i get **unable to resolve class org.codehause.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder** error

I understand that it could not import the class mentioned in the plugin class but i cannot figure out how to solve it. Please help me. This is the BuildConfig file.

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"

}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
    compile ":mail:1.0.7"
    compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"
    compile ":simple-captcha:0.9.9"

    //compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    //compile ":spring-security-appinfo:2.0-RC2"
    //compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
    //compile ":spring-security-acl:2.0-RC1"
    //compile ":searchable:0.6.9"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.7.4"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of this plugin. I've [fixed this issue](https://github.com/domurtag/grails-simple-captcha/issues/4) in version 1.0.0 of the plugin, so you can replace the following in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile ":simple-captcha:0.9.9"
runtime ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
```

with

```
compile ":simple-captcha:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ":simple-captcha:0.9.9"
runtime ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
```

try that under it - it is listed in the plugin bugs

also in your config you have it twice any reason ?

Comment: That worked @vahid; and i had that twice by mistake.